# How to get Google Fitness API data using OAuth2 with PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-oauth, google-fit

I'm having problems getting the data from the Google Fitness API to use into my application, using Node and Express. Here's a portion of the `app.js`:

```
app.get('/auth/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', 
        { scope: ['profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write'] }
));
app.get('<callback url>', 
    passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
        res.json(req.user);
});
```

As you see I'm requesting for 2 distinct scopes. Here's my strategy using `passport-google-oauth20`
Here's my strategy for this particular datapoints of the `passport.js`:

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL:'<callback url>'
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            console.log(profile);
        } 
    )
)
```

The problem however, is that in the console, I only get the first scope `"profile"` with all its properties but there's no fitness related info. Any idea what's wrong with it? Should I use a different strategy implementation? At the moment, this code hangs to the sign in of google and console logs the profile info which is normal.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: someone correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldnt you now be able to call the fitness api with the requested accessToken? (`https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources`) see: `https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to `@griFlo`'s comment. Once I obtained the access token from the authentication process, I had to use this and every other that's been generated to call the api I wanted, which I did using a request promise from the `request-promise` module inside the strategy.

First install the module using `npm i request-promise` and require the module to the topside of your app. The code should look like this:

```
//other defines
...
const request = require('request-promise');

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        // options for google strategy
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL:'<callback url>'
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            User.findOne({googleId: profile.id}).then((currentUser) => {
                if (currentUser){
                    // check user
                    done(null, currentUser);
                } else {
                    //call fitness api
                    url = keys.google.fitnessUrl;
                    request.get(url).auth(null, null, true, accessToken)
                      .then(res=> {
                        new User({
                                googleId: profile.id,
                                ....
                                activity: res
                            }
                        ).save().then((newUser) => {
                           done(null, newUser);
                      });  
                    });
                } 
        });
}));
```

The important part is within the mongoose promise part where you check the user before calling the api so you can add the fetched data into the pre-defined schema and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct scope is: `fitness.activity.read`

Comment: `write` is view AND store https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#fitnessv1